# Selecting an appropriate statistical test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, z-test

I have two sets of data (>10k observations), each having a binary feature describing the activity of every customer within the groups (1=active, 0=inactive).

I've seen parametric tests being used to compare proportions (z-test) of the 2 groups, but I have also seen it being tested with a non-parametric test (chi-squared).

Which test is appropriate for comparing the proportions of active customers of these two sets?

Comment: If you want to compare rates between two groups (e.g. probabiity of doing X) then a z test is fine.  What is really more important is how the data were collected and what question you want to answer.

Comment: thanks Demetri, would the answer change if the question is not about doing X, but being X? e.g. comparing the proportions of brown eyes in two groups? In what situations (i.e., questions I want to answer) would the z-test be more suitable than the chi-squared one? Ultimately, I want to determine if both groups are representative.

Comment: It might be best to ask about what you really want to do, rather than assuming you have to do a statistical test and that the z-test and chi-squared test are your two options.

Comment: I want to identify any bias in two groups that (only in theory) are randomly sampled from a larger population.

Comment: @simon You won't be able to detect bias with a statistical test.  Edit your question to ask exactly what you want and we can tru to help.